# Is there a way to use CSS transition without defining any properties?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have a JavaScript function to move different child elements across a parent div, but I want to add a transition so the elements  move  to their new position in the div instead of changing the position instantly.

As far as I used transitions, for me it only worked with defined properties, like `top`/`bottom` or `height`/`width`. In this case, I didn't define any properties, so I wonder if a transition effect is still possible.

Here you can see the children and the parent I set up, and my function for moving the child elements:

```js
function moveElement(elementId, place) {
  let div = document.getElementById('parent')
  let element = document.getElementById(String(elementId))
  let referencenode = div.children[place]
  div.insertBefore(element, referencenode)
}

var children = document.getElementById('parent').children;

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let id = children.item(2).id;
  moveElement(id, 0)
});
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1" style="background-color:red" class="child">
    <p>child1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="child2" style="background-color:lightblue" class="child">
    <p>child2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="child3" style="background-color:green" class="child">
    <p>child3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="child4" style="background-color:yellow" class="child">
    <p>child4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

since all my attempts of making a working transition failed, I only left the switching function, so they switch places instantly.

I tried using `transition-duration`, but since no CSS properties were defined, expected nothing happened.

Thanks in advance!

And please no jQuery, since I didn't ever use it, so if possible I would appreciate vanilla JavaScript :)

Comment: JQuery supports this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321465/animated-insertbefore-in-javascript)

Comment: You have to transition *something*, your choices are something *specific* or **everything**. Also note there are some properties that cannot be transitioned/animated.

Comment: `transition` only influces the way in which (certain) CSS properties are applied which the DOM remains unchanged. If you use DOM operations like `insertBefore` to change the relative order of HTML elements, `transition` has no effect on this at all, no matter which CSS properties you specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments suggest, CSS transitions happen on CSS property changes, so some CSS property has to change for a transition to happen. For animating changes in order or DOM elements, you could consider using the *First, Last, Invert, Play* (FLIP) technique<sup>1</sup><sup>2</sup><sup>3</sup><sup>4</sup> whereby:

1. **First**: get the initial position of the element(s).
2. **Last**: make the element(s) to their ending state.
3. **Invert**: use the information from the previous steps to invert the positional change back to how the element(s) look before the change occurred.
4. **Play**: remove the inversion but with transitions, so that the element(s)  animate back from inversion back to their new positions.

```js
function moveElement(elementId, place) {
  let div = document.getElementById('parent')
  let element = document.getElementById(String(elementId))
  
  const children = Array.from(element.parentElement.children);
  let referencenode = children[place]
  
  // Get the child index of the element being moved.
  const elementIndex = children.indexOf(element);
  // Get the list of elements that will move.
  const movingChildren = children.slice(
    elementIndex > place ? place : elementIndex,
    (elementIndex > place ? elementIndex : place) + 1,
  );
  
  // Capture the positions of the elements being moved (First).
  const before = movingChildren.map(
    movingChild => movingChild.getBoundingClientRect(),
  );  
  
  // Do the moving (Last).
  div.insertBefore(element, referencenode);
  
  // Do the animations.
  movingChildren.forEach((child, i) => {
    // Get the moved position.
    const newPosition = child.getBoundingClientRect();
    // `transform` the element back to their old position (Invert).
    child.style.transform = `translate(${before[i].x - newPosition.x}px, ${before[i].y - newPosition.y}px)`;
    
    // Initialize the transition on the next render frame.
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      // Clear transitioning.
      const clearTransition = () => {
        child.style.transition = '';
        child.removeEventListener('transitionend', clearTransition);
      };
      child.addEventListener('transitionend', clearTransition);
      
      // Do the transition (Play).
      child.style.transition = 'transform 250ms';
      child.style.transform = '';
    });
  });  
}

var children = document.getElementById('parent').children;

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let id = children.item(2).id;
  moveElement(id, 0)
});
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1" style="background-color:red" class="child">
    <p>child1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="child2" style="background-color:lightblue" class="child">
    <p>child2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="child3" style="background-color:green" class="child">
    <p>child3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="child4" style="background-color:yellow" class="child">
    <p>child4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>[Layout Animation FLIP Technique](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/css-animations/layout-animation-flip-technique/)</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>[Animating Layouts with the FLIP Technique](https://css-tricks.com/animating-layouts-with-the-flip-technique/)</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup>[FLIP Your Animations](https://aerotwist.com/blog/flip-your-animations/)</sup>

<sup><sup>4</sup>[Animating the Unanimatable](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/animating-the-unanimatable/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

## Rearrange sibling elements with animation

- Store the current boundingClientRect of all the elements that need to move (basically all the elements from minIndex to maxIndex included)
- Move the element into the new DOM position index (within the same parent) taking care that: if the index matches the total indexes available, you'll have to ***append*** the moving element by passing `null` as the second argument `ParentElement.insertBefore(elToInsert, null)`, or by using `ParentElement.append(elToInsert)`.
- Use the [Animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API) to `translate` the elements from the starting boundingClientRect (before the rearrangement) to the current one (0px left and top):

```js
const moveElement = (elA, iB) => {
  const par = elA.parentElement
  const ch = [...par.children];
  const elB = ch[iB];
  const iA = ch.indexOf(elA);
  const iTot = ch.length - 1;
  const iMin = Math.min(iA, iB, 0);
  const iMax = Math.max(iA, iB, iTot);
  const chMove = ch.slice(iMin, iMax + 1);
  const bcr = chMove.map(el => el.getBoundingClientRect());

  // Rearrange
  par.insertBefore(elA, iB === iTot ? null : elB); 
  
  // Animate elements
  chMove.forEach((el, i) => { 
    const {left: xA, top: yA} = bcr[i];
    const {left: xB, top: yB} = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    el.animate([
      { translate: `${xA - xB}px ${yA - yB}px`},
      { translate: "0px 0px" },
    ], { duration: 280 });
  });
};

const par = document.querySelector("#parent");
par.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const elA = par.children[2];
  moveElement(elA, 0);
});
```

```html
Click to rearrange + animate
<div id="parent">
  <p style="background:#0bf;">A</p>
  <p style="background:#fb0;">B</p>
  <p style="background:#f0b;">C</p>
  <p style="background:#bf0;">D</p>
</div>
```